# How write this in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have problems for insert dynamic id into function of JavaScript the code:

```
$('#scroll-up1, #scroll-down1').bind({ ..............
```

In this example I need the function to take values of id I send across the function

```
$('#scroll-up+id, #scroll-down+id').bind({ ..............
```

The problem it´s the quotes as " or ' no works for me and I can´t use right for function works fine , this script let me scroll text ok but only problem with this because no let me send values right from id of function.

EDIT FOR ME FOR PUT ALL CODE : .....

```
PHP AND HTML CODE

<?php

$fil_comments=file("comments.txt");

for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($fil_comments);$i++)
{

$line=explode("~",$fil_comments[$i]);

if ($i%2==0)
{
$back=1;
}
else
{
$back=2;
}

?>


<li>
<div id="web_comment_<?php echo $back?>">

<div id="web_comment_name"><?php echo $line[0];?></div>
<div class="web_comment_texto" id="scroll<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $line[1];?></div>
<div class="web_comment_arrow" style="margin-left:260px;" id="scroll-down<?php echo $i;?>"><img src="imagenes/comments/arrow_up.png"></div>
<div class="web_comment_arrow" style="margin-left:288px;" id="scroll-up<?php echo $i;?>"><img src="imagenes/comments/arrow_down.png"></div>

</div>
</li>


<script>
scroll_diver(<?php echo $i;?>);
</script>



<?
}

?>
```

FUNCTION OF JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function scroll_diver(id)
{





$(function() {




    var ele   = $('#scroll'+id);
    var speed = 30, scroll = 5, scrolling;

    $('#scroll-up'+id).mouseenter(function() {
        // Scroll the element up
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-down'+id).mouseenter(function() {
        // Scroll the element down
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
        }, speed);
    });


    //var a='#scroll-up'+id;
    //var b='#scroll-down'+id;


    var a='#scroll-up'+id;
    var b='#scroll-down'+id;



    //$('a,b').bind({
    //$('#scroll-up1, #scroll-down1').bind({
    //$('#scroll-up'+id+',#scroll-down'+id)
```

/// THE PROBLEM HERE !!!

```
    $('#scroll-up'+id+', #scroll-down '+id).bind({



        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
});

}
</script>
```

Basically the problem it´s in the line of JavaScript function for send id, if you see the PHP code, I use bucle for for create scrolling tips with informations and in each I can scroll his content, for this I call function into the bucle with:

```
<script>
    scroll_diver(<?php echo $i;?>);
    </script>
```

But in this line no send right information for works ok, if I use out bucle for one specific id, works ok , with this works yes but scroll up and down crazy fast , and the controls no works fine.

Comment: `$('#scroll-up'+id+', #scroll-down'+id).bind({`

Comment: It's just a string, are you telling me you've *never* concatenated a variable into a string before?

Comment: Oh, wow. Unfortunately, I don't have time to help you through this, but you really 1) don't need to be calling that via a function ('scroll_driver'), 2) should be initializing your handlers using a standard practice (like using `$(function() { // all my binders })` to fire them after the DOM is ready...) ... sorry, just don't have time, now that I'm off lunch break.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to look at something like this:

```
$('#scroll-up' + id + ', #scroll-down' + id).bind({ ..............
```

As a commentor mentioned, jQuery selectors are simply strings. You can put them together as you see fit. In this case, I'm concatenating the id (which for simplest examples, I'm assuming is a number or other unique identifier) to the #scroll-up selector, so if your id was "1", you would end up with a string, effectively, that looks like:

```
'#scroll-up1, #scroll-down1'
```

after the string concatenation occurs.

Also, it might be worth noting that you'd probably get better bang for your buck if you simply gave both objects the same class, then inside your binding function, work out which item called and perform your scrolling appropriately.

So, if you had:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="scroll-up1" class="scroller"><!-- and code --></div>
    <div id="scroll-down1" class="scroller"><!-- and code --></div>
</div>
```

then your javascript could look like this, avoiding the need for concatenation:

```
$('.container').on("mouseover",'.scroller', function(){
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");

    if(thisId == "scroll-up1"){
        // do your up-scroll
    } else if(thisId == "scroll-down1") {
        // do your down-scroll
    }
});
```

Mind you, that uses .on(), which is preferred over .bind(), but the idea is to handle it based on a common class, rather than having to modify your selector every time you go to bind your event handler for those items.

Comment: I'd suggest you explain that selectors are just strings so the OP can just use javascript to build the desired selector string.

Comment: You are trying to look for #scroll-up{number}, and #scroll-down{number}, where {number} is the id-number of the item you're trying to bind to, right? If so, this should work... otherwise, infensus' tip should work if you're looking for an element with a set id inside #scroll-up or #scroll-down.

Comment: I put all script and you can see well , regards !!

Answer (score 0):

Recommended solution: use CLASS NAMES for COMMON FEATURES

`$('.scroll-up, .scroll-down').bind({`

or even:

`$('.scroll').bind({`

Answer (score -1):

```
var id = 38;
$('#scroll-up' + id + ', #scroll-down' + id).bind({ ..............
```

Comment: I think id=number.. not another id

Comment: You have spaces in your selector which render it broken.

Comment: @meagar actually you are wrong the spaces make no difference so it is better to put them there than in the variable. Check before you down vote please.

It turns out he meant numbers but that wasn't specified when I posted. Edited answer.

Comment: We can all see your edit history, and we can all see that you *removed* the spaces I'm talking about, the ones that supposedly "make no difference". They *were* wrong, and would have produced a broken, nonsense selector. The question clearly indicated he was trying to produce a selector like `scroll-up1`, while your code produced selectors like `scroll-up 1`, which is not only incorrect, it is completely invalid.

Comment: seems like you are not reading what I am writing..
1) the original post had less info so I thought he wanted to do '#someid1 #someid2' but it turned out he wanted to do '#id45'
2) $('#something ') IS a valid selector, learn before you make guessed statements.

Comment: `$('#something 1')` is *not* a valid selector, and that is what your code was generating. Your *original* code, prior to your edit, did *not* produce `#someid1`. It produced `#someid 1`. This was wrong. Your updated answer is no better, as it contains nothing but code with *no explanation* of what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: do you honestly think that one if these http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13091692/revisions is producing '#something 1' :/